# Can OneDrive API be used to access newly introduced tags for images in onedrive

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

We have an application that integrates heavily with Microsoft OneDrive that uses [OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/index.htm). Is it in anyway possible to access newly introduced [OneDrive Photo Tags](https://blogs.office.com/2015/01/27/introducing-an-all-new-way-to-view-manage-and-share-your-photos-in-onedrive/) through the API?

What i need to do is things like listing the tags and get the photos that has a some kind of tag.
I've been through the API documentations but couldn't find a way. Is there a way that i missed?